# How to achieve page object mechanism with Geb Spock Appium

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, spock, geb

I am effectively using geb-spock for our web application. I am new to geb spock appium and struggling with PageObject mechanism in Appium as I have comfortably achieved that for web application.

I am successfully able to launch the App and able to perform some actions on app with below code.

```
@Stepwise
class TC_001_DictionaryApp_Spec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "Step 1:Go to the login page of the WU"() {
        when: "User is on Dictionary App"
        // at AppHomePage

        and: " User enters the value in Searh box"
        /*page.textboxSearch.value("Obsess")*/
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.dictionary.mr:id/input_text_view")).sendKeys("Obsess")

        and: "Press the Enter"

        then: "Word should be searched"
    }
}
```

However if I try to use `at` or `to` block then its getting failed. (If you un-comment the code in the above test case it's not working) Below is my page object class

```
class AppHomePage extends Page {
    static at = {}

    static content ={
        textboxSearch (wait:true) { driver.findElement(By.id("com.dictionary.mr:id/input_text_view")) }
    }
}
```

Can you please guide me how I can achieve the page object mechanism with geb spock appium.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't added an assertion in your "at" block so it will fail.

```
class AppHomePage extends Page {

    static at = { title == "my title assertion"}

    static content ={
        textboxSearch (wait:true) { driver.findElement(By.id("com.dictionary.mr:id/input_text_view")) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. If this is the web page then I can understand that there will be baseUrl and some title to it, However I am not sure how the Andriod App will have baseUrl and title. Please guide me how we can get this for Andriod App...eg. say whatsApp

Comment: So you need to make an assertion in the "at" block.  Does it run if you put something simple in there like 1 == 1

Comment: Yes, by putting 1 == 1 in at block solved my problem.

Comment: Great, i'm glad my answer solved your problem.  You will want to change that 1 == 1 into a more meaningful assertion now.

Comment: Yes, It's my bad that I got confused this simple thing to consider it for mobile App. Thanks a lot.